# Fallo en exportar xcode could not attach to pid 3307

Tags: ionic, xcode

hice una aplicación con ionic y funciona correctamente cuando lo probé en xcode, tiene los certificados solo para desarrollo, antes yo exportaba el ipa y si se instalaba en itunes, pero ahora no se instala, se muestra que se esta instalando y luego desaparece, saben alguien ¿porque razón?.

Al probarlo en ejecutar con el emulador me sale un error en xcode `Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode  unable to attach`. Pero aun asi me funciona en el emulador sera por eso que no se deja instalar de itunes?

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises este [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema era que Apple cambio los acuerdos de políticas y privacidad y en la cuenta donde estaba no estaban aceptadas, al momento de archivar para esportar el ipa escoger la opción `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment` y ver siempre que están bien los certificados. Y con eso se dejo instalar desde itunes.